# $f(x)\geq e^x$ implies $xf'(x)/f(x)\to \infty$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is it true that $f(x)\geq e^x$ for large $x$ implies $xf'(x)/f(x)\to \infty$? We assume that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Certainly not. It's easy to imagine a function $f(x)$ dominating $e^x$ but having periodic "humps" where $f'=0$. A better question is if $\limsup \frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)} = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show $\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)} = +\infty$. If we let $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{e^x}$, then $g(x) \ge 1$ and $x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = x(1+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)})$ for each $x$. If the limsup of this were not $+\infty$, then $g'(x)$ must be less than $-g(x) \le -1$ for all large $x$. But this contradicts $g(x) \ge 1$ for all large $x$.